# How to find value that occurs more than N/3 times in linear time and constant space

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm going over the following coding problem:

> You’re given a read only array of n integers. Find out if any integer
>   occurs more than n/3 times in the array in linear time and constant
>   additional space.
>
> If so, return the integer. If not, return -1.
>
> If there are multiple solutions, return any one.
>
> Example :
>
> Input : [1 2 3 1 1]
>   Output : 1
>   1 occurs 3 times which is more than 5/3 times.

I was able to solve it with this Python code:

```
class Solution:
    # @param A : tuple of integers
    # @return an integer
    def repeatedNumber(self, A):
        tracking = dict()

        for i in A:
            if i in tracking:
                tracking[i] += 1
            else:
                tracking[i] = 1
        #print tracking
        results =  []
        for k in tracking:
            if tracking[k] > len(A)/3:
                results.append(k)
        #print results
        return -1 if len(results) < 1 else results[0]
```

The solution passes the test cases, but does it meet the requirements? And if not, how can it be made to meet them?

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. Note first that Python has a style guide, PEP-8.

Comment: This code uses more than "constant additional space." Your `tracking` dictionary may have up to `n` entries, if all the array's entries are distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is correct, but uses more than *O(1)* space, so it does not fit with the requirements.

This problem is a variation on the majority vote problem, where the occurrence factor must be more than *n/2* instead of *n/3*.

For the *n/2* case the [Boyer–Moore majority vote algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_majority_vote_algorithm) can be used, so I have been looking into finding a variation of this algorithm that would work for the *n/3* case.

The counter which is used in Boyer-Moore would have to remain positive for a longer time to ensure a frequent value "survives" long enough to be recognised as a solution. This can be achieved by incrementing the counter with 2 when the value matches the currently retained value, and decrementing it by 1 (like in Boyer-More) when it differs from it.

Although that looks promising, it will fail identifying candidates that occur while the counter is decrementing, since the number of decrements can be *2n/3*. The solution I propose to prevent this from happening is to use several counters, which work almost independently: they each track a *different* value. When one of them drops to zero, and the current value is not one of the other values being tracked, the zero-counter is bound to this new value, and starts incrementing again (with 2 at a time).

I found that with 4 such parallel counters -- and corresponding tracked values -- the algorithm never misses a good candidate.

When the end of the array is reached, the algorithm will have 4 candidates (if the array has at least 4 elements of course). The second sweep which is done in Boyer-More, is then also performed here, but by counting the occurrences of each of the 4 candidates. If any of those values occurs more than *n/3* times, the solution has been found. If not, it is concluded there is no such value in the array.

Compared with the Boyer-More algorithm, this variation of it uses 4 times more time and 4 times more space, but that does not change the complexity: it still spends *O(n)* time and uses *O(1)* space.

Here is the code:

```
def commonNumber(a):
    counts = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    values = [None, None, None, None]
    for value in a:
        is_not_tracked = value not in values
        for i, count in enumerate(counts):
            if count == 0 and is_not_tracked:
                values[i] = value
            counts[i] += 2 if value == values[i] else -1 if count else 0
    # second phase: count the occurrences for each of the 4 candidates
    for value in values:
        if a.count(value) > len(a) // 3:
            return value
    return None
```

It can be made to work with three counters, if we increment the counters with 1 only, but don't decrement them if the current value matches with any of the three tracked values:

```
def commonNumber(a):
    counts = [0, 0, 0]
    values = [None, None, None]
    for value in a:
        try: # when value is being tracked, increase its counter
            counts[values.index(value)] += 1
        except ValueError:
            try: # otherwise reassign a depleted counter to this value 
                i = counts.index(0)
                values[i] = value
                counts[i] = 1
            except ValueError: 
                # if no counter available: ignore value, and decrement all counters
                counts[:] = [count - 1 for count in counts]
    # second phase: count the occurrences for each of the 3 candidates
    for value in values:
        if a.count(value) > len(a) // 3:
            return value
    return None
```

I tested this code with many arrays having a solution. Such arrays can be built by having -1 occurring just the minimum number of times needed to be considered a solution, then -2 occurring one time less, the value -3 once, and then a list of non-negative random values to fill up the remainder. That remainder list has fewer elements than needed for a value to be a solution, so such arrays always have -1 as solution.

Here is one of the code blocks I have tested with:

```
import random
size = 100
repeat = size//3 +1
a = [-1]*repeat + [-2]*(repeat-1) + [-3] + [int(i*random.random()) for i in range(size-2*repeat)]
for i in range(1000):
    random.shuffle(a)
    result = commonNumber(a)
    # Verify that the outcome is as expected: it should be value -1
    if result != -1: 
        print('fail:', a, result)
print('done')
```